# Aparecer resultado na mesma página com php

Tags: php, html

Estou basicamente iniciando os estudos com PHP e o que estou tentando fazer é simples. Gostaria de exibir o resultado de um cálculo numa mesma página.

Segue a estrutura do meu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meus códigos:

index.php:

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>

<?php include "footer.php"; ?>
```

header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="calc.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="num1">
    <input type="text" name="num2">
    <select name="cal" id="">
        <option value="add">Add</option>
        <option value="sub">Subtract</option>
        <option value="mul">Multiply</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

calc.php:

```
<?php

 include 'includes/calc.inc.php';

$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];
$cal = $_POST['cal'];

$calculator = new Calc($num1, $num2, $cal);
echo $calculator->setCalc(); //gostaria de mostrar na mesma página
```

calc.inc.php:

```
<?php

class Calc{
    public $num1;
    public $num2;
    public $cal;

    public function __construct($num1, $num2, $cal){
        $this->num1 = $num1;
        $this->num2 = $num2;
        $this->cal = $cal;
    }

    public function setCalc(){
        switch($this->cal){
            case 'add':
                $result = $this->num1 + $this->num2;
                break;
            case 'sub':
                $result = $this->num1 - $this->num2;
                break;
            case 'mul':
                $result = $this->num1 * $this->num2;
                break;
            default:
                $result = "Error";
                break;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Recupero os valores na *index.php* com o arquivo *calc.php.* E no arquivo *calc.php* eu passo os valores para o *calc.inc.php* para que neste os cálculos sejam realizados e seja retornado o valor final para o *calc.php.* O problema é que no *method* é redirecionado para a página *calc.php* e o resultado é exibido nesta outra página, **sendo que eu gostaria que aparecesse na mesma página da index.php.**

Tentei fazer algo com *Header(“Location: index.php”)* mas isto faz com que a página atualize, então, não resolveu.
É possível fazer o que quero? Aceito diferentes tipos de soluções!

Comment: Você pode verificar se foi disparado o `POST`, caso seja `POST` é só exibir o resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu index adicione o calc.php

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>
<?php include "calc.php"; ?>    
<?php include "footer.php"; ?>
```

No calc.php verifique se foi enviado algum post.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
  include 'includes/calc.inc.php';

  $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
  $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
  $cal = $_POST['cal'];

  $calculator = new Calc($num1, $num2, $cal);
  echo $calculator->setCalc();
}
?>
```

E não esqueça de trocar a action para index.php

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: claro que está bem simples, foi mais para te passar a lógica.

Comment: Deu certo a sua proposta! Contudo, apareceu mensagens de erro na página index.php: 

Notice: Undefined index: num1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\calc.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: num2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\calc.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: cal in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\calc.php on line 8
Error

Consegue me ajudar nisso?

Comment: Ajustei! no if(isset($_POST)){} faltou colocar o nome do que eu gostaria de verificar! E também estava faltando o nome do botão! Então no header.php no <button type="submit">Calculate</button> foi adicionado a propriedade name="submit"... Resultado final: <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button> e no if: if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {} e o resultado final deu certo!

Comment: Boa! É isso aí. Com o tempo você vai pegando a prática e fica automático testar com isset se o campo que vai ser usado existe. Acabei não colocando eles pq foquei no conceito apenas. Flw.

Answer (score 1):

**calc.php**

```
include 'includes/calc.inc.php';

$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];
$cal = $_POST['cal'];

$calculator = new Calc($num1, $num2, $cal);
$result = $calculator->setCalc(); //gostaria de mostrar na mesma página

header("Location: index.php?cal=$result");
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="calc.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="num1">
    <input type="text" name="num2">
    <select name="cal" id="">
        <option value="add">Add</option>
        <option value="sub">Subtract</option>
        <option value="mul">Multiply</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>

<?php
  if (isset($_GET["cal"])){
      echo $_GET["cal"];
  }
?>
```

> Na calc.php foi usado a sintaxe de cabeçalho "Location" passando como valor do parâmetro o resultado do calculo

```
header("Location: index.php?cal=$result");
```

> Na header.php recuperamos esse valor para aparecer na index.php

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET["cal"])){
      echo $_GET["cal"];
  }
?>
```

Na verdade, o trecho de código imediatamente acima, não precisa ser incluído na `Na header.php`, pode ser incluído na `index.php` ou na `footer.php`, dando assim oportunidade de se colocar o resultado no local exato onde quer que ele apareça dentro da página.

Comment: Testei aqui e deu certo da sua maneira! Dei um +1 para sua resposta porque ela foi útil sim, mas a resposta do Cleytinho foi o que mais correspondeu, por isso selecionei ela como correta! Mas grato mesmo assim... É uma alternativa para solucionar o mesmo problema.